# Setting gap/margin between radiobuttons that are created by run time

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I am creating custom radiobuttons in code. Here is the custom radioButton class

```
public class SurveyRadioButton extends RadioButton {

private int value;
private int questionId;

public SurveyRadioButton(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_checkbox);

    setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());

    setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);

    setTextSize(17);

}


public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public int getQuestionId() {
    return questionId;
}

public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
    this.questionId = questionId;
}
```

}

and there goes creating script

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams matchWrapLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(SplashActivity.this);

    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(matchWrapLayoutParams);

    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++) {


            SurveyRadioButton radioButton = new SurveyRadioButton(this);

            radioButton.setLayoutParams(matchWrapLayoutParams);

            radioButton.setText("arda");

            radioButton.setSelected(false);

            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }

        root.addView(radioGroup);

    }
```

These codes makes that views, but i want to add gap between radiobuttons. Setting margin into the layout params does not work. I am wondering what will be ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any clever solution. But adding blank view to radiogroup handles this.

```
        SurveyRadioButton radioButton = new SurveyRadioButton(this);

        radioButton.setLayoutParams(matchWrapLayoutParams);

        radioButton.setText("arda");

        radioButton.setSelected(false);

        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

        //Above 4 rows for blank view
        View blankView = new View(QuestionActivity.this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams matchWrapLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);

        blankView.setLayoutParams(matchWrapLayoutParams);

        radioGroup.addView(blankView);
```